# GWT: sharing POJOs with MySQL

Tags: mysql, gwt, pojo

I have a client who wants to use GWT with MySQL. What's the best way to share POJOs between the GWT front-end and the SQL back-end? Is [Gilead](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/index.php?page=gwt) up to the task? Is there something better?

Comment: I tried Gilead recently ... and after a day of trying to set it up I gave up. I event posted question here. So I gave up and write DTOs. If you'll eventually decide to uce Gilead, please see my question about Gilead and maybe you'll be able to provide some useful answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) . Here is the discussion about them ; [Gilead vs RequestFactory](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/5d78850d323faecb/c042dad39f5dd1c2)

Comment: Interesting. Seems like you still need to define go-between proxy objects, but there's certainly something to be said for using what comes in the box with GWT.  Thanks.